# Force "Group by" in a folder in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-explorer

I have a specific folder that I want to be always opened with `Group by date` view, in the Windows File explorer.

Every now and then, when I reopen this folder, it comes back to the default folder view with `Group by...` disabled.

**How to force this folder to be always displayed with "Group by"?**

[image]

I have already tried "Customize this folder..." but without success here.

Can I force this by editing a `desktop.ini` file? Or another method?

Comment: Try opening a root folder with numerous files. Go to the top of the folder, set your file option settings and then click on Apply to Folders.  That sometimes works.

Comment: `Appy to Folders` will set `Group by` for *all* folders that share the folder's *FolderType* (General/Generic, Documents, Music, Pictures, etc.), not one specific folder.

Answer (score 1):

Several possible causes for what you're describing:

1. Saved views are indexed by their *[NameSpace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/namespace-intro)* path, so pay attention to what's displayed in the Explorer Address bar. For instance, if your folder is a subfolder of your Documents folder, you want to navigate to and set your view for these paths:

   - `This PC > Documents > SubFolder`
   - `This PC > Windows (C:) > Users > <ProfileFolder> > Documents > SubFolder`
   - `<FullUserNameFolder> > Documents > SubFolder`
2. The default limit for number of saved views is 5000. You may be "maxed out", in which case Windows will delete an existing saved view to save a newer one.

   To determine if you've maxed out, copy & pate the following command into a **PwerShell** window and press `<Enter>`. It will return the count of saved views:

   - `((gp "HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU").Nodeslots).count`

   If you've maxed out, you have to delete all saved views and "start over". But custom defaults you've set via `Apply to Folders` will be retained. To delete all saved views, delete the following two registry keys:

   - `HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU`
   - `HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags`